# Choosing between ListView and Grid in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have just started developing with Xamarin, and in me getting familiar with the different views/ui controls - given that `ListView` has an `ItemTemplate` property, which seems I can use to "embed" any combination of views I want - should I then go with `ListView` or `Grid` when I care about displaying different views in a single row ?

I mean, using a ListView with a StackLayout as template, with Stack orientation set to Horizontal... vs a grid ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Xamarin.Forms Control Gallery it states the following:

**ListView:** https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/controls/views/

> An ItemView that displays a collection of data as a vertical list.

**Grid:** https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/controls/layouts/

> A layout containing views arranged in rows and columns.

Therefore from those two definitions you can derive the following:

If you have a list of Employees I would use a `ListView`

Where as if I have a login Form where I need to display a username and password box it would be correct to use a Grid. Using a list be more difficult and give less flexability.

Obviously the final decision is up to you